# validate name with jquery with some custom functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am working on simple form validation with jQuery

In fact I used jQuery plugin to validate email address field, now I wanna put an individual validation for `name` field I tried it too, but it's not working and I am unable to figure out the problem behind.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Makes "field" required and an email address.</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
   $( "#myform" ).validate({
           rules: {
                   name: {
                           required: true,
                           minlength: 4,
                           maxlength: 20,
                           customvalidation: true
                   }
           },
           messages: {
                   name: {
                           required: "Dude, enter a name",
                           minlength: $.format("Keep typing, at least {0} characters required!"),
                           maxlength: $.format("Whoa! Maximum {0} characters allowed!")
                   }
           }
   });
   $.validator.addMethod("customvalidation",
           function(value, element) {
                   return /^[A-Za-z\d=#$%@_ -]+$/.test(value);
           },
   "Sorry, no special characters allowed"
   );
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="navbar">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a id="clickBack" href="backPage.htm">clickBack</a></li>
        <li><a id="clickForward" href="forwardPage.htm">goForward</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><br><br>
<label for="field"> Name: </label>
<input class="left" id="name" name="name" minlength="4" class="required name"/>
<br/>
<form id="myform" method="post" action="">
<label for="field">Email: </label>
<input class="left" id="field" name="field" />
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
debug: true,
success: "valid"
});
$( "#myform" ).validate({
rules: {
field: {
required: true,
email: true
}
}
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

need some guidance... Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"..Can you be more specific ?

Comment: it is not validating name field but email field is fine, it is being validated.

Comment: I think in the required field it should be either true or false and you have given string over there.

Comment: nops i tried it is not working... but these are the messages na.....

Answer (score 3):

Try using this best JQuery validation [plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation)

```
username: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
        },

messages: {
        username: {
        required: "Please enter a username",
        minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters"
        },
```

If you want custom validation you can try this:

```
 $.validator.addMethod("customvalidation", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z0-9\-]+$/i.test(value);
    }, "Username must contain only letters, numbers, or dashes.");
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi a few points which might help this work :

- Try use an id that is not "reserved" or ambiguos (since `name` is already an attribute of the element it could be misleading.  When I got your script working on my side, it would work with `id="firstName"` for eg. but not `id="name"`)
- Make sure the element you're validating is in the form you're running the validation on (in your code sample, the name element is sitting outside `myform`
- Combine the two `$("#myform").validate(...)` methods in two different script blocks, you don't need a seperate one for email and name, you can list them together!

Hope that helps, good luck!

Comment: yeah i wanna combine these two but even then it won't work....  :(
how to do it..?